# Error al instalar tema Bridge en WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Al instalar un tema en WordPress (Bridge) me sale este mensaje:

```
El sitio tiene problemas técnicos. Mira si han llegado instrucciones a la bandeja de 
correo electrónico del administrador del sitio.
```

No recibo ningún correo al administrador del sitio y no se como solucionar la instalación de dicho tema. He visto que renombrando el tema puedo volver al admin sin problema pero no consigo saber que es lo que esta fallando con el tema. ¿Alguna idea de cómo obtener algo de información para instalar el tema?

Answer (score 0):

puedes obtener más información haciendo en Debug de errores. Para hacer esto configura la WP-DEBUG que se encuentra en config.php en TRUE, y con eso puedes visualizar los errores al refrescar la web.

Comment: ¿Eso es de Wordpress o del tema en concreto? Veo que en Wordpress hay un archivo wp-config.php?¿Te refieres a ese?

Comment: Bueno, finalmente localizé wp-config.php en Wordpress y sustituí 'WP_DEBUG', false); por: define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); El problema persiste. He reiniciado Xampp por si acaso y sigue apareciendo el mismo mensaje. ¿Hay algo que me haya pasado por alto?

Comment: Hola, y cuales son los nuevos mensajes que te aparecen?

Comment: Pues sigue apareciendo lo mismo que al principio es decir: "El sitio tiene problemas técnicos. Mira si han llegado instrucciones a la bandeja de 
correo electrónico del administrador del sitio" y "constant REQUEST_URI - assumed 'REQUEST_URI' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PruebaWordPressBridge\wp-content\themes\twentynineteen\functions.php". El segundo error pude resolverlo añadiendo comillas a REQUEST_URI pero el primer error que inidica que el sitio tiene problemas tecnicos no aporta nada mas datos sobre dicho error y no se como continuar.

Comment: ¿Alguna idea? Gracias

Comment: Nueva información: como te decía en lo que es el navegador no se carga el admin como antes y muestra el mensaje: "". Por otra parte en la consola aparece este mensaje: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)". ¿Puede esto ayudar a encontrar el error?